# Does any version of QGIS support GDB 10.5?

Tags: qgis, vector, file-geodatabase

Does any version of QGIS support GDB 10.5? I have a GDB 10.5 file that I need to open in QGIS and I can't. I'm using QGIS 3.6.

The file is named Virginia_Parcel_Dataset_2018Q4.gdb -- it can be downloaded here: https://vgin.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=29627d7c051a47dc8ce71b4484531ab3

Comment: QGIS uses GDAL to open geodatabases. According to https://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html, "The FileGDB driver provides read and write access to vector layers of File Geodatabases (.gdb directories) created by ArcGIS 10 and above. The dataset name must be the directory/folder name, and it must end with the .gdb extension." Also it can't open compressed geodatabases.

Comment: @csk yes, so that means it should be able to open in QGIS. The file is named Virginia_Parcel_Dataset_2018Q4.gdb  -- it can be downloaded here: https://vgin.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=29627d7c051a47dc8ce71b4484531ab3 -- maybe you can test it out?

Comment: Is this the same file? It's available as a shapefile. https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/d0945119ac1d44398b662c21f74d8080_0

Comment: Also here: https://ftp.vgingis.com/Download/VirginiaParcel.zip

Comment: @csk there is an issue with the shapefile where the unique ID to join the attribute tables is incorrect. See this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313975/losing-numeric-table-precision-during-shapefile-export-in-arcgis-pro

Comment: I tried loading the geodatabase into QGIS 3.4.5, and got this error message: "download with protocol source type has failed, do you want to try the file source type?" so I posted a [bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21433). And now we wait. (In the meantime, try the kml and spreadsheet versions from the first link I posted from hub.arcgis.com.)

Comment: There has only been one file geodatabase format since the release of the FGDB API.  There might be features unaddressable in earlier releases of ArcGIS, but at the API level, it's only simple tables.

Comment: @vince So are you saying that the version number is a red herring? The fact is that QGIS won't open this gdb, but I don't know enough about gdb format to look at this one and see if there's something wrong with the file itself. Can you have a look at it?

Comment: File geodatabase isn't a *file*, it's a directory with dozens to hundreds (or much more) files.  It's possible the data is corrupt, but I cannot evaluate that at this time. This is an issue to address with the data provider.