# Losing numeric table precision during shapefile export in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, attribute-table, export, precision

I'm trying to export a GDB file version 10.5 in ArcGIS Pro 2.0.0 to a shapefile, but every time I do, I lose precision with the unique feature IDs. For example the IDs will go from 554423216 --> 554423210.000

This taints the data b/c now each feature does not have a unique ID, plus I can't accurately join attribute tables.

Why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: do you have multi-point/line/polygon geometry?

Comment: @Mapperz yes, I do have multi-polygon geometry

Comment: so for a shapefile you will need to do multi-part to single part first > http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm

Comment: that will solve the issue in the attribute table?

Comment: most likely yes as you will have separate object-ids to a shapefile..

Comment: This is the sort of rounding associated with a 4-byte IEEE floating-point data type. Look again at how the column is interpreted.

Comment: @Vince is there column format type that would prevent this from happening?

Comment: It depends on the format of the source type. Please [Edit] the question to provide this detail. You should also include the exact version of Pro in use.

Comment: @vince I updated the question. ArcGIS Pro 2.0.0. GDB 10.5.

Comment: Since Pro is now at 2.3.1, you probably want to try something modern before addressing a potential bug like this. Note that your update didn't include the column definition in the FGDB and shapefile

Comment: @Vince updating now

Comment: @Vince updated to 2.3.1 and still got the problem. added a screenshot of the result in shapefile

Comment: We cannot help without knowing the datatypes involved.

Comment: @Vince how do I get you that information?

Comment: Place it in the question body. As ASCII, preferably, but as a screenshot if necessary.

Comment: Create a blank Shapefile from your input data. In Catalog, change VGIN_QPID type to Long Integer, then Append the blank Shapefile.

Comment: @vince how do I figure out whether or not the file is ASCII?

Comment: @Klewis what tool do I use to chagne VGIN_QPID to a long integer?

Comment: Not the file, the definition. If you right-click from Catalog, the Fields tab shows Field Name and Data Type.  Providing this for the source  (in the body of the Q) will give an indication if there's any chance the dBase conversion has a hope of working.